# How do I print an item and the list it came from in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a roulette simulator and currently the program only prints the number. How do I get it to print the number and the list title it is in?

Example:

12 Red

22 Black

```
import random
red=[1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36]
black=[2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35]
spin=random.randint(0,36)
print(spin)
```

Comment: are the numbers in both the list unique . In other words is red-black=null

Comment: just a comment: there are zero and double zero in roulette, and they are green.

Comment: Yes, there are no numbers that appear in multiple lists.

Comment: Posted the answer. But I see there is no 0 in both the list. So please take care of it. I won't make the changes . :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure and get green numbers covered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if spin in red:
    print('{} Red'.format(spin))
elif spin in black:
    print('{} Black'.format(spin))
else:
    print('{}'.format(spin))
```

Comment: I like this answer because it considers the output for '0' and '00'.

Comment: One quick question? Instead of printing 0 (if it occurs) shouldn't we ask for a spin again?

Comment: No, in actual roulette there are spaces corresponding to '0' and '00' which are neither red or black. If you bet on red you get double your money if the ball lands on red. So with the extra '0' and '00'  the probability of you winning is slightly less than 0.5. This is how the casino makes money over time.

There should be some adjustment of the simulation for '00'. Maybe extend to 37 and print '00' if it lands on 37.

Comment: You could choose the format string and then format and print `spin` separately.

Answer (score 2):

You only need check two conditions, either it is `0` or in one of red or black, if it is not 0 and not in red in must be it black

```
import random

red = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36}
spin = random.randint(0, 36)
print("{} {}".format(spin, ["black","red"][spin in red] if spin != 0 else "green"))
```

Which written out explicitly becomes:

```
red = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36}

spin = random.randint(0, 36)
if spin == 0:
   print("green 0")
elif spin in red:
    print("red {}".format(spin))
else:
    print("black {}".format(spin))
```

The black list of numbers is irrelevant.

If you want to represent `00` you will need to use strings instead of integers as a leading 0 means octal in python 2 and is invalid syntax in python3

```
import random

red = {'25', '12', '14', '16', '19', '32', '30', '23', '36', '34', '1', '3', '27', '5', '7', '18', '9', '21'}

nums = ["00",'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35']

spin = random.choice(nums)
if spin  in {"0","00"}:
   print("green {}".format(spin))
elif spin in red:
    print("red {}".format(spin))
else:
    print("black {}".format(spin))
```

you could also use a dict mapping numbers to colour and picking a random key:

```
d = {'00':"green",'0':"green",'24': 'black', '25': 'red', '26': 'black', '27': 'red', '20': 'black',
     '21': 'red', '22': 'black', '23': 'red', '28': 'black', '29': 'black', '1': 'red', '3': 'red',
     '2': 'black', '5': 'red', '4': 'black', '7': 'red', '6': 'black', '9': 'red', '8': 'black',
     '11': 'black', '10': 'black', '13': 'black', '12': 'red', '15': 'black', '14': 'red', '17':
    'black', '16': 'red', '19': 'red', '18': 'red', '31': 'black', '30': 'red', '36': 'red', '35':
    'black', '34': 'red', '33': 'black', '32': 'red'}

spin = random.choice(list(d))
print("{} {}".format(d[spin],spin))
```

If you want to get the percentages you can run `n` trials and use a Counter dict to keep count:

```
nums = list(d)

from collections import Counter

num_count = Counter()
colours = Counter()
for test in range(10000):
    spin = random.choice(nums)
    num_count[spin] += 1
    colours[d[spin]] += 1


for k,v in colours.most_common():
    print("{} rolled {} times which is {}% of the total spin".format(k,v, v / 10000.0 * 100))
print(" ")
for k,v in num_count.most_common():
    print("{} rolled {} times which is {}% of the total spins".format(k,v, v / 10000.0 * 100))
```

Output:

```
black rolled 4748 times which is 47.48% of the total spin
red rolled 4726 times which is 47.26% of the total spin
green rolled 526 times which is 5.26% of the total spin

20 rolled 301 times which is 3.01% of the total spins
36 rolled 296 times which is 2.96% of the total spins
23 rolled 292 times which is 2.92% of the total spins
3 rolled 285 times which is 2.85% of the total spins
00 rolled 284 times which is 2.84% of the total spins
13 rolled 282 times which is 2.82% of the total spins
12 rolled 280 times which is 2.8% of the total spins
27 rolled 278 times which is 2.78% of the total spins
15 rolled 273 times which is 2.73% of the total spins
14 rolled 272 times which is 2.72% of the total spins
6 rolled 270 times which is 2.7% of the total spins
8 rolled 270 times which is 2.7% of the total spins
2 rolled 268 times which is 2.68% of the total spins
5 rolled 267 times which is 2.67% of the total spins
35 rolled 267 times which is 2.67% of the total spins
19 rolled 266 times which is 2.66% of the total spins
34 rolled 265 times which is 2.65% of the total spins
33 rolled 265 times which is 2.65% of the total spins
21 rolled 264 times which is 2.64% of the total spins
4 rolled 264 times which is 2.64% of the total spins
24 rolled 263 times which is 2.63% of the total spins
17 rolled 262 times which is 2.62% of the total spins
31 rolled 261 times which is 2.61% of the total spins
11 rolled 260 times which is 2.6% of the total spins
18 rolled 257 times which is 2.57% of the total spins
29 rolled 255 times which is 2.55% of the total spins
30 rolled 253 times which is 2.53% of the total spins
10 rolled 251 times which is 2.51% of the total spins
22 rolled 248 times which is 2.48% of the total spins
28 rolled 247 times which is 2.47% of the total spins
1 rolled 245 times which is 2.45% of the total spins
25 rolled 243 times which is 2.43% of the total spins
32 rolled 243 times which is 2.43% of the total spins
0 rolled 242 times which is 2.42% of the total spins
9 rolled 242 times which is 2.42% of the total spins
26 rolled 241 times which is 2.41% of the total spins
7 rolled 240 times which is 2.4% of the total spins
16 rolled 238 times which is 2.38% of the total spins
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can search using 'in' operator.

```
if spin in red:
    //do for red
elif spin in black:
    //do for black...
else:
    //take a spin again
```